# Why Splunk map command does not work as expected

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

I have this splunk command to search events from my splunk logs; it first attempts to find the ownerId, gets the stats of the traceId and attempts to iterate through the same log using the traceId (I'm trying to use the top-level requests traceId and using it I want to find the logs somewhere down in the requests, i.e. my service making requests to another service)

```
`my_service` ownerId=1234 OR ownerId=3456
| spath output=traceId path=tr.traceId
| stats count by traceId
| map maxsearches=8 search="search `my_service` tr.name="*Request*" tr.spanId=$traceId"
```

This only lists the events from the first search, isn't the map supposed to pick up each traceIds and iterate through the same source and list only the matching events?

Comment: Might be a typo but tokens inside the `map` command (and elsewhere) must have a `$` on both ends. `| map maxsearches=8 search="search `my_service` tr.name="*Request*" tr.spanId=$traceId$"`

Comment: Thanks @RichG it worked after adding the closing ‘$’ sign. However the result is so unpredictable.